# TSQL adjustable time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a TSQL query that is returning a list of variable names and their values at a point in time. Currently it is truncating the datetime column to give me a minute-by-minute result set.

It would be incredibly useful to me to be able to specify whatever interval of data I want. Every x seconds, every x minutes, or every x hours.

I cannot GROUP BY because I do not want to aggregate the selected values.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT time, var_name, value
FROM (
    SELECT time, var_name, value, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by var_id, convert(varchar(16), time, 121) order by time desc) as seqnum
    FROM var_values vv 
    JOIN var_names vn ON vn.id = vv.tag_id
    WHERE ( var_id = 1 OR var_id = 2)
        AND time >= '2013-06-04 00:00:00' AND time < '2013-06-04 16:20:17'
) k
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY time;
```

And the result set:

```
2013-06-04 00:20:52.847     Random.Boolean   0
2013-06-04 00:20:52.850     Random.Int1      76
2013-06-04 00:21:52.893     Random.Boolean   1
2013-06-04 00:21:52.897     Random.Int1      46
2013-06-04 00:22:52.920     Random.Boolean   1
2013-06-04 00:22:52.927     Random.Int1      120
```

Also just to be complete, I want to retain the ability to modify the WHERE clause to choose which var_id's I want in my result set.

Comment: *"Currently it is truncating the datetime column to give me a minute-by-minute result set."* Are you sure your current query is doing that? If it's not, what is it *supposed* to be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to partition by the unix timestamp divided by your required interval in seconds;

```
(PARTITION BY var_id, DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, time) / 60  -- 60 seconds
 ORDER BY TIME DESC) AS seqnum
```

The calculation will give the same result for 60 seconds, which will put all rows in the interval inside the same partition.